# How to style material-ui select component with style-components (not material-ui classes!) in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, select, material-ui

I am struggling with styling my material-ui select component with styled-components, instead of material- classes. I am using material-ui/core 4.12.3.

If i use for example old makeStyles component from material and create my own classes it works just fine, as well as for example styling inline or via menuProps.

Works

```
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    icon: {
      top: 0,
      marginRight: '1px',
    },
    selectRoot: {
      '&:focus': {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: '10px',
      },
    },
  }))
```

Works

```
          <StyledSelect>
          classes={
            {
              //icon: classes.icon,
              //root: classes.selectRoot,
            }
          }

      MenuProps={{
        anchorOrigin: {
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'left',
        },

        getContentAnchorEl: null,
        style: {
          maxHeight: 400,
        },
      }}
                  style={{
                    border: '1px solid grey',
                    backgroundColor: 'white',
                    borderRadius: '10px',
                    width: '140px',
                    height: '40px',
                  }}
</StyledSelect>
```

But for the project integrity and restriction i prefer to style with style-components.

So far, i only managed to change letters color. Nothing else really works, even if i try to style it with use of classess names appeared in dev tools.

DOES NOT WORKS (sadly)

```
  StyledSelect: styled(Select)`
  border: '1px solid grey';
  backgroundColor: white;
  borderRadius: '10px';
  width: '140px';
  height: '40px'

  '&:focus': {
    backgroundColor: 'white';
    background-color: 'white';
    borderRadius: '10px',
  };
  .MuiSelect-select:focus {
    backgroundColor: 'white';
    background-color: 'white';
    borderRadius: '10px',
  },
    &.MuiSelect-select:focus {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      background-color: 'white',
      borderRadius: '10px',
    },
    & .MuiInputBase-formControl {
      border-color: red;
    }
    icon: {
      top: 0,
      marginRight: '1px',
    },
```

Material documention does not really that helpfull in this case.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't doing much since Material UI components are not simple HTML elements. For example, if you look in the HTML tree in dev tools, a "Select" is rendered not as a `<select>...</select>` but rather as...

```html
<div>
  <label />
  <div>
    <div />
    <input />
    <svg>
      <path />
    </svg>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <span />
      </legend>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

The styles are nested at various levels of the above component tree, so to modify a particular border or background style, you will have to know exactly which element to target using a specific selector (since the `id` properties change on every render).

Instead, you can continue to use the [css properties provided in the material documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html), but do not attempt to replace the Material UI root component by defining it as a styled component. If you wrap the Material Select component in another div of your own, made with styled-components, then you can pass down those attributes to the children Material elements similar to how you are doing now.

Some attributes will need a "!important" flag to override the style in Material, and some will require you to use the `somethingProps` (e.g. "menuProps", "inputProps", etc.) properties in order to override the style. This is because while overriding it manually with the class name from the docs and a "!important" flag is very good at targeting one (or a couple) of the components in the tree, when you use the `somethingProps` properties, Material will automatically cascade those styles to the right elements in the tree.

Comment: It actually works, but is slow as hell, reading the proper tree structure in dev tools. Anyway thank you, its clear for me now.